# setting a custom deleter for std::unique_ptr with a non-static member function

Tags: c++

How do I set a member function as a custom deleter for `std::unique_ptr`?

```
class foo{
public:
    foo() = default;
};

class fooDeleter{
public:
    fooDeleter() = default;
    
    void deleteFoo(foo* f) {
        cout << "deleting foo" << endl;
        delete f;
    }
};


int main() {
    fooDeleter* fd = new fooDeleter;
    using fptr = void (fooDeleter::*)(foo *f);
    fptr p = &fooDeleter::deleteFoo;
    
    std::unique_ptr<foo, fptr> fooptr{nullptr, (fd->*p)}; // syntax error

}
```

This works, but I can't figure out how to set a deleter...

```
foo* f = new foo;
(fd->*p)(f);
```

- edit:
  The custom deleter is declared as a non-static methods in JNI library, so I can't change it.
  So the final deleter *must* be a non-static methods.

Comment: Make the function static.

Comment: Yes, nothing in your example uses the `this` value in `fooDeleter` so it should work as a static class function.

Comment: It's just an example, guys..

Answer (score 1):

Short answer - you can’t use a non-static method *directly* as a deleter. That is simply not what `unique_ptr` is expecting. You must use either:

- a stand-alone function, or a static method.
- a lambda.
- a functor (an object with an `operator()` implemented).

For example:

```cpp
class foo{
public:
    foo() = default;
};

void deleteFoo(foo* f) {
    cout << "deleting foo" << endl;
    delete f;
}

int main() {
    foo* f = new foo;
    std::unique_ptr<foo, decltype(&deleteFoo)> fooptr{f, &deleteFoo};
}
```

```cpp
class foo{
public:
    foo() = default;
};

int main() {
    foo *f = new foo;
    auto deleter = [](foo* f){
        cout << “deleting foo” << endl;
        delete f;
    };
    std::unique_ptr<foo, decltype(deleter)> fooptr{f, deleter};
}
```

```cpp
class foo{
public:
    foo() = default;
};

struct fooDeleter{
    void operator()(foo* f) {
        cout << "deleting foo" << endl;
        delete f;
    }
};

int main() {
    foo *f = new foo;
    std::unique_ptr<foo, fooDeleter> fooptr{f};
}
```

So, to have the deleter call a non-static method, you will have to wrap the call to the method inside one of those options.  For instance, inside a custom functor that has a `std::function` member pointing at the method, and then the `operator()` can call that function. Or a lambda that captures the desired method and calls it.  Or the functor returned by `std::bind()`'ing the method directly.

Comment: The custom deleter is declared in JNI library as a non-static member function, so I can't change it. I'll try the third one. Thanks for your kind explanation